# Xamarin forms API Get not working in release mode

Tags: android, asp.net-web-api, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2019

I have a problem with my app in Xamarin Forms.
The GET request works in debug mode but not in release mode.
The POST request works in both mode.
I test on real device and emulator Android.
The api path is HTTPS and the app has INTERNET permission.

This is the code:

```
                if (IsConnected)
            {
                string jsonRequest = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(request);
                StringContent content = new StringContent(jsonRequest, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

                var Request = new HttpRequestMessage
                {
                    Method = HttpMethod.Get,
                    RequestUri = new Uri(client.BaseAddress + $"api/Servizi/getServizi"),
                    Content = content
                };


                var jsonResponse = await client.SendAsync(Request);//.ConfigureAwait(false);



                var contents = await jsonResponse.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                response = await Task.Run(() => JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ServiziResponse>(contents));
            }
```

Comment: "not working" is not a helpful description of the problem.  Do you get an error or exception?  Are you getting any response code at all?  Is the request even reaching your server?  Have you tried a tool like Wireshark to compare the requests in debug and release modes?

Comment: I have no exceptions. I don't have any response but I think that the request does not start. Contents is blank and resonse is null

Answer (score 0):

In visual Studio Add this line in Android Options
[VS19](https://i.stack.imgur.com/we28I.png)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).